# Java MessageFormat - issue escaping characters

Tags: java, android, messageformat

I define a String in my strings.xml file:

```
<string name="unformatted_string">Here\'s a song I\'ve created just for you\! {0}</string>
```

And then I fetch that string and using MessageFormat.format, I replace {0} with a URL:

```
String str = MessageFormat.format(getString(R.string.unformatted_string), url);
```

When I print str, I see this:

```
Heres a song Ive created just for you http://www.google.com
```

The [MessageFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) states that rules for quotes are somewhat confusing, and then goes on to provide only a single example that only uses double-quotes. From my reading of the documentation, it seems my single-quote woes could be solved by using ''':

```
<string name="unformatted_string">Here'''s a song I'''ve created just for you\! {0}</string>
```

But the Android Resource Packaging step throws an error because I have an apostrophe not preceded by a `\`.

My only requirement is that the string be defined in strings.xml (to support localization).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file is an android resoure file, which mandates that every apostrophe is escaped with a preceding backslah. And MessageFormat requires every apostrophe in the pattern to be doubled. So you need two escaped apostrophes:

```
<string name="unformatted_string">Here\'\'s a song I\'\'ve created just for you\! {0}</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XML, you can use the entity  `&#39;` for the apostrophe.

However, the android resource does some further processing after parsing the XML and requires that apostrophes to be escaped with a backslash - regardless of whether they are represented as a entity or placed directly in the markup.  This has nothing to do with XML.  See [guidelines here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).  Yuck!  XML already offer complete encoding for all possible characters, it is a shame that the android system decided to put this unnecessary layer this on top.

Finally, the formatting of a message for output requires that apostrophes be doubled because apostrophe is the escape character for [Java MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

Comment: Android Resource Packaging step still throws an error when using &#39;

Comment: Hmm, well that is standard XML.  Perhaps you need to put two of them in, e.g.  `&#39;&#39;` however that is quite ugly.

Comment: Yeah, I think you still need to escape it so that would work. JB's solution is a bit cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All sources (Google, Unicode) recommend to use single quote \u2019 ’ for human-readable text, and limit usage of the ASCII apostrophe (\u0027 ' ) to program syntax.

> RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
> = single comma quotation mark
> • this is the preferred character to use for
> apostrophe

This completely avoids problems like yours.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_single_quotation_mark

[https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/quotes.html)